# Intensity to pixel conversion

Tags: pixel, java-2d

I hava a data of images 20 x 20 pixel in the form of intensities normalized by anti-aliasing.I took this 
data from [THE MNIST DATABASE](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)
I want to convert these intensities to pixel (0-255) so that i can visualize these grayscale images it in java. Also why there are negative values(-1 to 1).

Answer (score 0):

Whats hard about converting a range of values from -1 to +1 to a range of 0 to 255. Simply multiply each component (the -1 to +1] by 255/2 and round.

Comment: pixel = 128 + ( value[x] * 127 )